# Gson TypeAdapter's write method is still called even if the field is set not to be serialized using Expose

Tags: java, gson

#### The Problem

```
@JsonAdapter(WatusiTypeAdapter.class)
@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = true)
private Watusi watusi;
```

If a `TypeAdapter` is present, the `Expose` annotation seems to be ignored. The `write` method of the `WatusiTypeAdapter` is still called, but `@Expose(serialize = true)` means it should not be. Perhaps the idea is that you should delegate that decision to the `TypeAdapter`, but that makes type adapters much less reusable.

#### The Question

Is this the expected behavior or a bug?

Comment: Your `serialize` is set to `true`, so `write` will be invoke to serialize the field.

Comment: Also, I assume you're using `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for catching that. It was just a bug in my question. And no, I'm not using `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation`. Perhaps that's the problem. Let me try that, although it will take some time because I have a lot of fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [javadoc of `@Expose`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) states

> This annotation **has no effect** unless you build `com.google.gson.Gson`
>   with a `com.google.gson.GsonBuilder` and invoke
>   `com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`
>   method.

Take this example

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
        example.other = new Other();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(example));
    }

    @JsonAdapter(value = OtherAdapter.class)
    @Expose(serialize = true)
    private Other other;
}

class Other {
}

class OtherAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Other> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Other value) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("hey");
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Other read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will produce

```
{}
```

In other words, `write` wasn't invoked.

This implies that all the fields you want to expose must be annotated with `@Expose`.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that in the documentation, but I'm glad I did. This answer will hopefully be useful to future Gson learners.